# se oculta el menú con ion-side-menus

Tags: angularjs, ionic

En unas ocasiones y rara vez se me oculta el menu cuando cambio de vistas por un rato o hago una interaccion, como enviar datos por un formulario. Lo hise con ion-side-menus saben alguna razón ¿porque se oculta? yo lo tengo así, muchas gracias:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" cache-view="false">
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <div class="row row-center row-no-padding main1">
        <div class="cj3">
            <div class="top flexCol">
                <div id="header" class="flexRow">
                    <div class="menuT" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><img src="img/menu.png" alt=""></span></div>
                    <div class="search" ng-click="abrirBuscador()"><div class="bus"><span class="icon-search"></span></div></div>
                    <div class="title flex-center"><span>{{tituloGeneral}}</span></div>
                    <div class="cart" ui-sref="app.canastika" style="position: relative;right: -10px;width: 18%;"><span class="icon-shopping"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-nav-view name="menuContent">
        </ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="left" class="menuAndorid42 row row-center row-no-padding"  expose-aside-when="large">
    <div id="cj1" class="cj1">
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ui-sref="app.home">
            <span class="icon-home"></span>
            <p>HOME</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ui-sref="app.perfil">
            <span class="icon-user"></span>
            <p>MI PERFIL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ng-click="suscriptoPetrocinio()">
            <span class="icon-hands"></span>
            <p>TUS <br>PATROCINADORES </p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ui-sref="app.terminos">
            <span class="icon-writte"></span>
            <p>TÉRMINOS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ui-sref="app.inviteamigo">
            <span class="icon-user-plus"></span>
            <p>INVITA <br> A UN AMIGO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ui-sref="app.contacto">
            <span class="icon-mail"></span>
            <p>CONTACTO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="iconSideMenu" menu-close ng-click="cerrarSesion()">
            <span class="icon-power"></span>
            <p>CERRRAR</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Comment: se oculta asi como que se pone blanco?

Comment: @sioesi se oculta el menu y navegación y solo queda el contenido de la vista

Comment: me ocurria lo mismo, hasta que me di cuenta de los errores en consola, trata de ver si tienes errores y ver porque se causan

Comment: @sioesi mas o menos puedes saber cual error es? es que me sale rara vez ese error.

Comment: no es un error en especifico, por ejemplo a mi me ocurria que tenia errores javascript y fui depurandolos y corrigiendo, nunca mas me paso.

Comment: @sioesi encontré el error es cuando le coloco el input type='tel', cuado le da click sigui del teclado me lo oculta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50477/discussion-between-sioesi-and-albert-arias).